# QUIT pygame event is not defined

Tags: python, events, pygame

I have two for loops:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_p:
                        banana = False
                        sportscar = True

for event in pygame.event.get:
                if event.type == QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()
```

Whenever I run my code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Calorie Calculator v2.py", line 43, in <module>
    if event.type == QUIT:
NameError: name 'QUIT' is not defined
```

I don't know why it does this, because before it worked perfectly.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Calorie Calculator v2.py", line 43, in <module>
        if event.type == pygame.event.QUIT:
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QUIT'

Comment: Thank You! I guess I just forgot. Post that as an answer an i'll pick it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `if event.type == QUIT:` to if `event.type == pygame.QUIT:`